# Ansible role variable becomes shortened

Tags: nginx, ansible

I'm using [this nginx role](https://github.com/jdauphant/ansible-role-nginx). When trying to configure the role via roles variables, it looks like this:

```
   - role: nginx
     nginx_sites:
        - server:
            file_name: 'ssl.mydomain.eu'
            listen: '443'
            server_name: 'mydomain.eu'
            root: '/dev/null'
            ssl: 'on'
            ssl_certificate: '/etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.eu.crt'
            ssl_certificate_key: '/etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.eu.key'
            ssl_protocols: 'TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2'
            ssl_ciphers: 'RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5'
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers: 'on'
            location1:
              name: '/'
              proxy_pass: 'http://localhost:10080'
              gzip: 'off'
              proxy_read_timeout: '300'
              proxy_connect_timeout: '300'
              proxy_redirect: 'off'
              proxy_set_header: 'Host               $http_host'
              proxy_set_header: 'X-Real-IP          $remote_addr'
              proxy_set_header: 'X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for'
              proxy_set_header: 'X-Forwarded-Proto  https'
              proxy_set_header: 'X-Frame-Options    SAMEORIGIN'
```

But the result, when parsed by ansible, is much shorter:

```
"nginx_sites": [
    {
        "server": {
            "file_name": "ssl.mydomain.eu",
            "listen": "443",
            "location1": {
                "gzip": "off",
                "name": "/",
                "proxy_connect_timeout": "300",
                "proxy_pass": "http://localhost:10080",
                "proxy_read_timeout": "300",
                "proxy_redirect": "off",
                "proxy_set_header": "X-Forwarded-Proto  https"
            },
            "root": "/dev/null",
            "server_name": "mydomain.eu",
            "ssl": "on",
            "ssl_certificate": "/etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.eu.crt",
            "ssl_certificate_key": "/etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.eu.key",
            "ssl_ciphers": "RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5",
            "ssl_prefer_server_ciphers": "on",
            "ssl_protocols": "TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see, there are some `proxy_set_header` entries missing. Is there some mistake I made, or is there a size limit in variables?

**Edit:** I can't have multiple keys with the same name. Any idea how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

reorganize the YML:

```
proxy_set_header:
    - '$http_host'
    - 'X-Real-IP          $remote_addr'
    - 'X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for'
    - 'X-Forwarded-Proto  https'
    - 'X-Frame-Options    SAMEORIGIN'
```

and loop through this array in the template